# Error when using trying to use angular2/Http

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-http

I have set up a project that is a copy of the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). Now I want to try and load some JSON so I amend `app.component.ts` to this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from "angular2/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Success</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private _http:Http){

    }
}
```

Adding the `import` is fine but as soon as I add `private http:Http` to my constructor I get errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         http:1
```

and

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         angular2-polyfills.js:1243
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/http
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

I'm guessing something is not compiling right but I am new to `Angular`, new to `Typescript`, new to `Node` -- Basically I could really use some help here.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, more importantly *WHY* it is wrong and how I can fix it and load some `JSON` to play with.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Check your Devtools Network tab for errors. `Unexpected token <` is most commonly caused by wrong link, for example if your server returns some `html` file instead of `json` you wanted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you forgot to include the http.dev.js file for the HTTP module of Angular2 into your main HTML file.

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

The error is the consequence of a 404 error when SystemJS tries to load this module.

Moreover you need to include HTTP providers when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
(...)

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Comment: You forgot the `angular2` part `<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>`

Comment: This cleared up the initial error but triggered more saying providers were missing for `ConnectionBackend` and `RequestOptions`. I added these and now am faced with `EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RequestOptions'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RequestOptions' is decorated with Injectable.` I'm not even trying to make a request yet, just get the parts loaded! Feels like I'm missing something here. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to specify `HTTP_PROVIDERS` when bootstrapping your application. I updated my answer ;-)

Comment: Awesome. It seems to be working now, thank you. All the examples I've seen just talk about the actual method of making requests once everything is plugged in but the whole stage of bootstrapping and configuring is bit of a mystery still. I'm hoping it will all just fall into place as I play around more. Anyway, thanks again, I really appreciate the help.